# Bootstrap 5: Create a card with a video

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this working [example](https://www.codeply.com/p/Pqu4ztUPRZ) in Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body pt-3 ">
            <h5 class="card-title">Camera streaming</h5>
            
            <div class="section d-flex justify-content-center embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <video id="remoteVideo" class="embed-responsive-item" controls autoplay loop muted></video>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 mt-2">
                    <button id="startButton" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" >Connect</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 mt-3">
                    <p><b>Status:</b> <span id="status">offline</span></p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

but is not working in [Bootstrap 5](https://www.codeply.com/p/pwbLVFt0OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body pt-3 ">
        <h5 class="card-title">Camera streaming</h5>
        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
          <video id="remoteVideo" controls autoplay loop muted></video>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <button id="startButton" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" title="" data-toggle="tooltip">Connect</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 mt-3">
            <p><b>Status:</b> <span id="status">offline</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```